# Disable button and send POST request

Tags: javascript

I've got a form that works slowly and I want to disable its submit button after clicking. I've done something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_pushbutton_disabled2 . But now my button can not send `POST` request. What do?

The code:

```
    <form id="command" action="/smsc/userRole/sms/sendMassSMS" method="POST">

            <a href="/smsc/userRole/sms/mass" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Нет,
                отмена</a>&#160;&#160;
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
                value="Да, отправляем" onclick="myFunction()" id="send">
    </form>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("send").disabled = true;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: show us the complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your myFunction() code with below

```
function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("send").disabled = true;
           document.getElementById("command").submit();
}
```